# Google Cloud Dataflow SplittableDoFn doesn't increase parallelism

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have following Apache Beam pipeline

```
pipeline
  .apply("Read lines", TextIO.read().from(options.getFileInput()))
  .apply("Split lines", ParDo.of(new LineSplittableDoFn()))
  .apply("Log bundles", ParDo.of(new ResultLogDoFn()));
```

- LineSplittableDoFn - Splittable DoFn implementation with @GetInitialRestriction, @ProcessElement with RestrictionTracker usage and @SplitRestriction.The DoFn splits the text line to 4 chunks.
- ResultLogDoFn - log unique bundles. Similar to code from https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-beam/data-partitioning-apache-beam/read

Based on my observations:

- Only TextIO.read() controls amount of created bundles.
- LineSplittableDoFn - creates and splits initial restrictions based on implemented logic, I can see it from my logs.
- New elements are created by LineSplittableDoFn and runner has ability to do work stealing based on restrictions.
- Number of parallel executions stay same. I can't add more workers or worker threads because there are no new bundles created during restrictions splitting. Based on my understanding of documentation bundle is a unit of parallelization in Beam world so parallelism depends on it: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/model/#dependent-parallellism

The solution with `Reshuffle` works fine. I can see increase in number of bundles and parallelism.

```
Reshuffle.ViaRandomKey<ShardedRequest> shuffle = Reshuffle.viaRandomKey();
Reshuffle.ViaRandomKey<ShardedRequest> partitionedShuffle = shuffle.withNumBuckets(100);
pipeline
  .apply("Read lines", TextIO.read().from(options.getFileInput()))
  .apply("Split lines", ParDo.of(new LineNonSplittableDoFn()))
  .apply(partitionedShuffle)
  .apply("Log bundles", ParDo.of(new ResultLogDoFn()))
```

I'm using Datafow Runner (via flex templates), Apache Beam version is `2.24.0`

Is it possible to increase number of bundles(and pipeline parallelism) using SplittableDoFn?